# SQLite and user functions

Tags: sqlite, callback

What values can an SQLite3 user function return?

A relevant example is adding a function for `regexp` - what values would it return to indicate a match or a non-match? Or must it be void?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Results are reported from SQLite3 functions (at the [C interface](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html) level) using the  `sqlite3_result_int` function (and its siblings, if returning other types).

```
void sqlite3_result_int(sqlite3_context*, int);
```

Report false by using a 0 for the second argument, and true by using a 1 (or other non-zero).

Comment: Thanks for this. More questions - 1. are there any other return values? eg. 2? -1? Also,  2. Does SQLite reserve a constant name for return 0 or 1 here? [eg. If it were an error return, 0 would be SQLITE_OK.]

Comment: @SK9: I don't think there's anything special there; SQLite's just using the usual C interpretation of boolean. You can pass back any integer value too, e.g., a count of the number of places in the string where the RE matches could be a reasonable thing to return (if a little expensive to compute in practice).

Answer (score 0):

On [this fossil repository](http://sqlite.mobigroup.ru/dir?name=ext) (which pulls from SQLite fossil repository regularly) you have some example of SQLite3 extensions, including add-ons that overload the `MATCH` function.

[Example of a function which overloads the REGEXP operator](http://sqlite.mobigroup.ru/artifact/bf4c9c5b807a60e2a65bc6fc483786635ba8ce5c)